# Evaluating a vector-variate function at multiple points in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, matrix, vector

Suppose that I have a vector-variate function, e.g.,

```
f = @(x)(x(1)+x(2));
```

I want to evaluate f at points x = [1; 1], [2; 2] and [3; 3]. These points are given in a matrix as:

```
x = [1 2 3;1 2 3]
```

I want to have the evaluations in a vector as:

```
[f([1;1]), f([2;2]), f([3;3])]
```

but I am not sure how to do that. Writing `f(x)` gives only one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can change the definition of you function, `f`, you just need to do this to vectorize over all of the columns:

```
f = @(x)(x(1,:)+x(2,:));
```

Then, when you call `f(x)` you'll obtain `[2 4 6]`.

You can learn more about the colon operator in the [documentation here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/colon.html).